# onmouseover not working in img tag in drupal

Tags: html, drupal, onmouseover

I am creating a node in drupal.
I have added `<img src="img.jpg">` tag in it and clicked on full HTML and it works well.
Now i want to add onmouseover effect on that image without editing CSS.

using img src tag in html is working fine but 
but onmouseover effect is not working.
With the above code the image is being displayed but rest of the code is appearing below the image. [image: Check the image here]

Answer (score 0):

You have an HTML syntax error in your code, probably a misplaced “>” character. Check the page (as served to browsers) with http://validator.w3.org to locate the error.